# what could i be doing wrong? am using turtle on my pycharm and my turtle.write method is not displaying on the screen

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, superclass, python-turtle

below are my scoreboard.py and main.py codes but after i click run, i can't see my score printed on the screen.

```
from turtle import Turtle
ALIGNMENT = "center"
FONT = ("Courier", 14, "normal")


class Scoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 270)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.write(f"Score: {self.score}", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write("GAME OVER", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)

    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.clear()
```

then my main.py

```
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
import time
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=500)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("my snake game")
screen.tracer(0)

snake = Snake()
food = Food()
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()
```

so, based on the two files: scoreboard and main.py respectively, what am i ommiting that prevents my score from being shown on my screen?

Comment: I don't see `update_scoreboard()` in `main.py` - so it can't write because you don't execute it. Code will NOT run it automatically - you have to write code to run it in every loop.

Comment: you set black background - but `write` displays black text - so you can't see text

Comment: window has height `500` and you write in position `(0, 270)` - so it will write outside window and you can't see it. Use for example `(0, 200)` to write inside window.

Answer (score 1):

Window has height `500` (`Y` in range `-250...250`) and you write in position `(0, 270)` - so it writes outside window and you can't see it.

Use for example `(0, 200)` to write inside window.

---

Full working example - all in one file so everyone can simply copy and run it.

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen
import time

ALIGNMENT = "center"
FONT = ("Courier", 14, "normal")

class Scoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 200)   # <-- HERE
        self.hideturtle()
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.write(f"Score: {self.score}", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write("GAME OVER", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)

    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.clear()
        

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=500)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("my snake game")
screen.tracer(0)

scoreboard = Scoreboard()

screen.listen()
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```